# Why a basis of the vector space $V=\{0\}$ is $B=\{\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that every $\vec{v}\in V$ can be written as $\vec{v}=a_1\vec{u_1}+...+a_n\vec{u_n}$, where $B=\{\vec{u_1},...,\vec{u_n}\}$ is a basis of the vector space. But I can't understand why a basis of the vector space $V=\{0\}$ is $B=\{\}$.

Comment: (useful) convention.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown This is certainly the easiest way to explain it to beginners. But it's a pet peeve of mine when trivialities involving the empty set are described as true by convention. In fact there are correct and coherent ways of reasoning about the empty set, which (almost always) lead to the desired "conventions". See my answer, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say that $B\subseteq V$ is a basis for a vector space $V$ is to say that (1) $B$ spans $V$, and (2) $B$ is linearly independent.

Unpacking the definitions of (1) and (2), we notice that for both, we have to think about *linear combinations* of elements of $B$. In general, if $B = \{b_1,\dots,b_n\}$, then a linear combination of elements from $B$ is something of the form $$\sum_{i=1}^n c_ib_i$$ where the $c_i$ are scalar coefficients. Note that there is one term in the sum for each element of $B$.

Ok, what happens when $B$ is empty? Then there are zero terms in the sum. And it is an important principle that **the sum of zero terms is the additive identity $0$** (likewise, the product of zero terms is the multiplicative identity $1$). So there is exactly one linear combination of elements of $B$, and it is the vector $0$.

Ok, why is (1) true? Well, to say $B = \varnothing$ spans $V = \{0\}$ is to say that every vector $v\in V$ is a linear combination of elements from $B$. But the only vector in $V$ is $v = 0$, and we've just seen that $0$ is the empty linear combination of elements of $B$.

And why is (2) true? To say that $B$ is linearly independent means that the only way we can write $0$ as a linear combination of elements of $B$ $$\sum_{i=1}^n c_ib_i = 0,$$ is if all of the scalar coefficients $c_i$ are $0$. We noted above that there is *exactly one* way to write $0$ as a linear combination of elements of $B$ (as the empty sum). Is it true that in the empty sum, all of the scalar coefficients $c_i$ are $0$? Yes, because there aren't any scalar coefficients.

(On the last point: it's another important principle that when there are no things of a certain kind, then all things of that kind satisfy any property you like. For example, all negative real numbers which have a real square root are integers. Also, all negative real numbers which have a real square root are unicorns. This is called vacuous truth.)

Answer (score 3):

Your question can be rephrased as:

1. Why $\text{span}(\varnothing)=\{0\}$?
2. Why $\varnothing$ is linearly independent?

Note that span of a set is the intersection of all subspaces containing it. So here intersection of all subspaces containing $\varnothing$ is $\{0\}$.

For the second one, suppose empty set is dependent. Then there are scalars so that the linear combination of elements of $\varnothing$ is zero. But in $\varnothing$, there is no element at all, so this cannot be happen and hence empty set is independent
Hence empty set is a basis for the trivial space

Comment: For your argument for point 2 to work, you need to show that there is some linearly independent set $I$ to begin with, so that you can note that $\varnothing \subseteq I$.

Comment: Thanks! Is it now okay?

Comment: Almost - it's not quite right to say that it can't happen that $0$ is a linear combination of elements of $\varnothing$. In fact, $0$ is the *empty* linear combination of elements of $\varnothing$. What's true is that in this empty linear combination, all of the scalar coefficients are $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\{0\}$ is $0$-dimensional:  there are no elements in a basis.

Comment: What's your definition of dimension? For me, when $V$ is a vector space, "$V$ is $0$-dimensional" means *by definition* that any basis for $V$ has $0$ elements. So using this statement as an explanation why $\varnothing$ is a basis for $\{0\}$ is circular.

Comment: I paused at that.  But I guess my point is that it's consistent.  @AlexKruckman

Comment: Do you mean "a convention that we call $\varnothing$ a basis for $V = \{0\}$ is consistent with an intuitively desirable convention that we say $V = \{0\}$ is $0$-dimensional"? I can agree with that, but it's not very satisfying!

Comment: I don't know @Alex, you're the doctor.   But you have to start somewhere.

Comment: Even Steinberg admitted once that math is a big circle.  I guess it's my attempt to make a long story short.  I used to have a copy of _Dimension Theory_.